# Where is the documentation on ompl_ros_interface?

Tags: ros, pr2-arm-navigation, ompl-ros-interface, ompl-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently updating my `katana_arm_navigation` stack (based on `pr2_arm_navigation`) from CTurtle to Diamondback. Especially in the OMPL part,  a lot seems to have changed, and I stumbled over a bunch of questions.

1. Is there any documentation on the parameters that `ompl_ros_interface` takes? More specifically, what is the format of the `ompl_planning.yaml` file? How to configure the different planners? Which planners can I use with my 5DoF arm, and how? ... and so on.
2. Is it necessary to provide my own version of `pr2_arm_kinematics/PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin`, or is there a generic one? Any documentation on that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9877/where-is-the-documentation-on-ompl_ros_interface?/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's on my plate :-)
Its coming soon, hopefully within the next 2-3 weeks.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) on 2011-05-26**:
Kadir, that's a good point. We'll revisit that API in e-turtle.

**Comment by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on 2011-05-26**:
Sachin, isn't that a little odd to name parent and the base link with the same frame id as it is already mentioned that the joint between them is fixed? The statement in the doc also makes me extra suspicious: " "world" should have been specified as the parent link of the "base" link of your robot".

**Comment by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) on 2011-05-24**:
If you have a fixed manipulator, i.e. an arm that is attached to the world using a fixed joint, that is correct. If you are working with a mobile manipulator where the arm is attached to a mobile base (e.g. like on the PR2), you will need to follow the example for the PR2 to configure things for your own robot.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-24**:
Ok, I went ahead and fixed some minor bugs. One question though: is it correct that in the first tutorial, both parent_frame_id and child_frame_id are "world"?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-23**:
Great, thanks a lot! :-)

**Comment by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) on 2011-05-23**:
Aah, good timing: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials :-)   Don't be shy about letting me know if things don't make sense or if something does not work - (if you find bugs, you are welcome to go ahead and edit the ROS wiki pages to correct them). I am still writing more tutorials.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-23**:
Hi Sachin, any news on that front?